# CSS property "user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only" causing problems on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have used "-webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only" in my css for a form.

It works for Safari and Chrome browsers.  But with Microsoft Edge browser, the input type="submit" isn't working, when removed Edge the form works.

How can I use the "user-modify" property in my CSS for Chrome and Safari, but not for Microsoft Edge?

Comment: That is interesting, but why not find an alternative anyway seeing as you need support for Edge? Or why bother testing Edge if you don't care about supporting it?

Comment: And what the heck has this question to do with JSP (other than that you your backend is JSP)? This is pure CSS/IE question.

Comment: @Jaunt. I have used Edge as the default browser fro my application on Windows10..Thats why i need to test on Edge.